# Why do the integers, rationals and any countable set have zero measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers, integers

There is an exercise in my text that tells me to prove the "obvious and easy to see" fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ have measure zero.

Er...here is what I know so far. If I have an interval, then the measure is the end point subtracting the initial point i.e. the length of that interval. What can I do to extend this line of thinking to $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ and any countable set?

Comment: The countability of the rationals lets you cover each point with an open set such that the sum of the measures of the sets is arbitrarily small. Use the countability and a geometric series summing to 1 to your advantage.

Comment: Note that this is true for any *countable subset of the real line* under the standard measure, not in all measures.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : it's true for every measure where singletons have measure zero

Comment: Sure, but that isn't all measures. @Tryss

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : sure, but your comment was very restrictive. I was just giving a necessary and sufficent condition for this property to hold

Answer (score 5):

Hints: enumerate any countable subset of $\mathbb R$ as, say, $\{a_n\}_n
\ge 1$. Now cover $a_n$ by an interval of length $\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$. What is the total measure of the cover? Notice that $\varepsilon>0$ may be chosen arbitrarily. What does that imply?

Answer (score 3):

This comes from the fact that a measure is countably additive.

Let $I$ be a countable set. You have then

$$\mu(I) = \mu ( \bigcup_{x\in I} \{x\} ) = \sum_{x\in I} \mu( \{x\} ) $$

Now **if every singleton has measure zero**, it follow that

$$\mu(I) = 0$$

And this is the case for the Lebesgue's measure on the real line.

Comment: Could you explain the part about "if every singleton as measure zero". What does it mean by a singleton?

Comment: @FemaleTank: a singleton is a set with exactly one element.