# What portion of real numbers are integers?

Tags: real-analysis

Purely for my own curiosity, I was wondering what portion of real numbers are integers. For example, if we start at $0$, and increase in increments of $1/2$, then $50\%$ of the numbers we come across will be an integer. If we increase in increments of $1/4$, then $25\%$ of the numbers are integers. However, if there are an infinite amount of real numbers between each integer, how do we express the portion of real numbers which are integers?

Comment: Integers have zero measure, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374991/why-do-the-integers-rationals-and-any-countable-set-have-zero-measure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0% of the real numbers are integers.

In technical terms we say that the integers are countable while the real numbers aren't, which amounts to saying that there are more real numbers than integers. If this seems trivial consider the fact that there are as many even integers as integers.

Take a look at Cantor's proof of this.

Comment: Cantor proof says that the reals have a greater cradianlity than the rationals